# Chen prime finder

Tags: python, python-2.x, primes

I've written a programme to find [Chen primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen_prime). A Chen prime *p* is a prime number where (*p* + 2) is either also a prime number or has two prime factors.

I've got it working to the best of my knowledge: the first few values are correct.

```
def isprime(n):
  for m in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
     if not n%m:
        return False
  return True
m = 2
while True:
    if isprime(m):
        b = (m + 2)
        if isprime(b):
            print(m)
        for i in range(2, int((b)**0.5)+1):
            if b%i == 0:
                if isprime(i):
                    j = b/i
                    if isprime(j):
                        print(m)
    m = m + 1
```

The `isprime(n)` function definitely works; it's the `while` loop I'm more concerned with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excessive nesting could be reduced with more Pythonic looping.  Since you are using Python 2, `xrange()` would be more appropriate than `range()`.  Also, `any(generator expression)` and `itertools.count()` would help reduce nesting.  To promote code reuse, the results should be `yield`ed instead of printed.

Here is a translation of your code, without changing the algorithm:

```
from itertools import count

def is_prime(n):
    """Test n for primality. Warning: invalid result for n <= 1."""
    return not any(n % f == 0 for f in xrange(2, int(n**.5) + 1))

def chen_primes():
    """Generate primes p where (p + 2) is either prime or a product of two
       primes."""
    for a, b in ((n, n + 2) for n in count(2)):
        if is_prime(a):
            if is_prime(b):
                yield a
            elif any(
                b % f == 0 and is_prime(f) and is_prime(b // f)
                for f in xrange(2, int(b**.5) + 1)
            ):
                yield a

for p in chen_primes():
    print p
```

@Caridorc has pointed out that your `isprime()` is technically incorrect, and you rightly observed that the bug makes no difference in this problem.  Even so, it is an issue that deserves to be clearly documented in a docstring.

---

You could define a `max_factor()` helper to reduce code repetition.  Note that with the proper logic, it is not necessary to test `i` for primality.  I also suggest doing special-case handling to take care of even numbers.

```
from itertools import count

def largest_factor(n):
    if n > 2 and n % 2 == 0:
        return n // 2
    for f in xrange(3, int(n**.5) + 1, 2):
        if n % f == 0:
            return n // f
    return n

def is_prime(n):
    return 1 < largest_factor(n) == n

def chen_primes():
    yield 2
    for a, b in ((n, n + 2) for n in count(3, 2)):
        if is_prime(a):
            f = largest_factor(b)
            if f == b or is_prime(f):
                yield a

for p in chen_primes():
    print p
```

Answer (score 2):

**\$0\$ and \$1\$ corner cases**

\$0\$ and \$1\$ are not primes, but your code returns:

```
>>> isprime(0), isprime(1)
(True, True)
```

**`is_chen_prime` function and helper function**

`is_chen_prime` should be a function of its own to improve re-usability.

A function to check if a number has two prime factors will make the code more similar to the mathematical description of the problem:

```
def is_chen_prime(n):
    return is_prime(n) and (is_prime(n + 2) or has_two_prime_factors(n + 2))
```

Comment: yeah I'm aware of that problem with 0 and 1 but it's irrelevant in this example as my starting value is 2. In versions to check if a number is a prime or where the problem is relevant I've set up the isprime(n) function differently to account for it.